# How to build Common Lisp project?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I'm new to CL and I can't figure out how to build binaries from my simple project.

I've created `app.asd` file with following contents:

```
(asdf:defsystem game
  :version "0.0.1"
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "main")))
```

`package.lisp` contents

```
(defpackage :app 
  (:use :common-lisp :asdf) 
  (:export :start))
```

and `main.lisp`

```
(in-package :app)

(defun start (args)
  (format t "Hello"))
```

I've also symlinked `app.asd` to `~/quicklisp/quicklisp/app.asd`, and when I execute

```
(require 'asdf)
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :app)
```

it looks like something compiles, but I can't find binaries/object files anywhere.

How do I build my project so I can copy it to another machine without CL installed and run?

I'm using sbcl 1.1.13 and asdf 3.0.2 on osx.

Comment: For new googlers: we can build a binary with `(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die :executable t …)`. Then `asdf:make` abstracts it for each implementation (the function name will differ on CCL, ECL…). See https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#with-asdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't put .asd files in `~/quicklisp/quicklisp/`. Use `~/quicklisp/local-projects/` instead.

The syntax for your `start` defun is wrong. It needs a lambda list.

Common Lisp is often used by starting the environment, loading the application, and then interactively calling functions defined by your application. The load process compiles the source code to machine code and the functions you call interactively are compiled functions.

When I want to make a binary file I can run from the command line, I use [buildapp](http://xach.com/lisp/buildapp/). In your case, you could do something like this:

```
sbcl --no-userinit --no-sysinit --non-interactive --load ~/quicklisp/setup.lisp \
  --eval '(ql:write-asdf-manifest-file "systems.txt")'

buildapp --manifest-file systems.txt \
  --manifest-file ~/quicklisp/local-projects/system-index.txt \
  --load-system game \
  --entry app::start \
  --output game
```

In this scheme, you would have to modify `app::start` to accept one argument, a list containing all the command line argument strings passed to `game`.

In general, most Common Lisps have some way to produce a binary program to run independently of the normal runtime. The terminology varies, but it's often called "delivery". If you use a different Common Lisp in the future, you may get more information if you search the documentation for information about delivery.

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal MISSING-COMPONENT: Component "game" not found`.

Comment: It may be that system-index.txt does not contain your game system yet; if you load it interactively, or add another batch call to sbcl to load it, it may show up there.